# Python - Iterating through list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list like;

```
list=[['1,2,3'], ['1,2'], ['1,2,3'], [1.0], [5.0]]
```

I would like to iterate through it to obtain the index value for each element, something like this;

```
orig_list=[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,5]
index_list=[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5]
```

(with indexes starting at 1)

Comment: Indexes start at 0, did you mean [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3,4]?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: oh sry, the index needs to start from 1.

Comment: try to make a full question and ask for the specific problem next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model is a bit strange. Lists containing only one element, being string or float. My answer applies to that strange case.

```
l=[['1,2,3'], ['1,2'], ['1,2,3'], [1.0], [5.0]]

orig_list=[]
index_list=[]

for i,item in enumerate(l,1):
    if isinstance(item[0],str):
        toks = [int(x) for x in item[0].split(",")]
        orig_list+=toks
        index_list+=[i]*len(toks)
    else:
        orig_list.append(int(item[0]))
        index_list.append(i)

print(orig_list)
print(index_list)
```

results in:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

`enumerate` gives you the index (start at 1). Depending on the type, either split + convert to int, or just convert to float. And create a list of the same index, or just append the current index.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_=[['1,2,3'], ['1,2'], ['1,2,3'], [1.0], [5.0]]

for x in list_:
    index_ = list_.index(x)

for x in list_:
    for y in x:
        index_ = list_.index(y)
```

Ii this what you was asking?

EDIT: if your index needs to start at one then simply + 1 to each index

```
indexs = [list_.index(x) for x in list_]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_=[['1,2,3'], ['1,2'], ['1,2,3'], [1.0], [5.0]]

orig_list = []
index_list = []
for x in list_:
    for y in x.split(","): #You can make a list out of a string with split functions.
        index_list.append(list_.index(x)+1)
        orig_list.append(float(y)) #Because you have floats and int in the strings I would convert them both to float.
```